# Add custom search query to Ubuntu activities search field

Tags: activities-overview

In Ubuntu, when i tap the Win key, the activities screen appears where i can type a search term. I am using [Ulauncher](https://ulauncher.io/) for quick access to some custom search queries. Is it possible to define search queries for the Ubuntu activities as well?

For example, i could define that when the search query starts with the keyword "i ", then i am searching on IMDB like: `https://www.imdb.com/find?q=%s` where s is the search term after the keyword "i ".

Is that possible and if so, how?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work like this in Ubuntu activities search. Searches there are provided by search providers. In Settings - Search, you can enable and disable different pre-installed search providers.

Third party search providers exist and can be added. The documentation indicates how one can [create a search provider](https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/search-provider.html).

If you do no write providers yourself, you depend on their existence, just like it is the case with Ulauncher. For example, to search IMDB, all I could find was an [abandonned project](https://github.com/Antergos/gnome-shell-search-providers) of 6 years ago.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will dig deeper into the topic of creating the search provider.

Comment: My workaround is now that i simply use a function in an alias in zsh. This way i can simply open search queries from the terminal. This is takes the same number of interaction steps and is quite versatile and easy to use. So in my .zshrc file i have for a query defined like this: `alias i='f() { xdg-open "https://www.imdb.com/find?q=$1" };f'`